# Persona 5 - Plant died

Tags: persona-5

After the time where we clean our room and get a plant, I honestly forgot I had it for a while (The day currently in my game is May 18th, and I first noticed it died May 6th). During that time, the plant apparently died, which I feel bad about. I'd like to get it back to health and take care of it from now on.

2 questions:

1) Where can I get the materials to bring it back to life/keep it healthy?

2) What benefits does it give me? Does it increase a social stat or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) You can buy plant nutrients of varying qualities from flower stores. You have one plant store available in the Underground Mall, and you'll unlock at least a couple more as the game goes on.

2.) You gain kindness when you add the nutrients to your plant. The more expensive the nutrients, the bigger the kindness boost. All of the nutrients "support" your plant for equal amounts of time and the plant can never officially die, so you're best off always giving it the most expensive nutrients available as soon as possible.